# convert days into month and remaining days using moment.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, momentjs

For example I've 250 Days and I want to convert it into months and days using moment.js so do you have any idea how can I do that?

```
Example:

What I've: 250 Days

What I want: 8 Months and 7 Days
```

Comment: Do you need to count months forward or backward starting from the current date-time?

Comment: why is 250 days 8 months and seven days? 250 days from 1 jan 2019 is 8 months 7 days (going forward), but it's 8 months 8 days from 1 feb 2019, 8 months 5 days from  1 mar 2019, 8 months 6 days from 1 apr 2019 ... see the problem with "what you want"?

Comment: This days being calculated from today and forward!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use `duration` together with `diff` to get the duration between these 2 dates

```js
const start = moment();
const end = moment().add(250, 'days');

const duration = moment.duration(end.diff(start));

const years = duration.years();
const months = duration.months();
const days = duration.days();

console.log(`years: ${years} months: ${months} days: ${days}`);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/momentjs/2.10.6/moment-with-locales.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: years is redundant, since 250 days is always less than 1 year :p

Comment: @JaromandaX Yes for 250 days it is.. but if the days is over 365 it isnt

Answer (score 3):

You can use [diff and duration](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/durations/diffing/) from moment to achieve this.

```
const currentDate = moment(new Date(), 'YYYY-MM-DD');
const futureDate = moment(currentDate).add(250, 'days');
const diff = moment.duration(futureDate.diff(currentDate));

console.log(`${diff.months()} Months and ${diff.days()} Days`);
// 8 Months and 6 Days
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
const futureDate = moment().add(250, 'days');
const duration = moment.duration(futureDate.diff(moment()));

console.log(`${duration.months()} Months and ${duration.days()} Days`);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.24.0/moment.min.js"></script>
```

> Note: it's a simplified example without edge-cases